# Setting the ghci prompt with colors

Tags: haskell, prompt, ghci

I try to use terminal colors within my ghci prompt.

So when I open `ghci` and try to:

```
Prelude> :set prompt '\[\033[1haskell > \033[0m\]'
'\[\033[1\]haskell> \[\033[0m\] '
```

I know that these codes are interpreted by bash with `echo` and the `-e` flag. But how can I do this within ghci?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to https://wiki.haskell.org/GHCi_in_colour, you can use

```
:set prompt "\ESC[33m\STXhaskell > \ESC[m\STX"
```

A few notes of explanation:

1. Only a double-quoted string is treated specially; single quotes are treated as part of the prompt.
2. The double-quoted string follows Haskell practice.
3. `\STX` corresponds to the `\]` of your `bash` prompt; <strike>it's not clear why GHCi does not require the equivalent of `\[` as well. (Perhaps it does; I haven't played with this much.)</strike>. See http://trac.haskell.org/haskeline/wiki/ControlSequencesInPrompt for an explanation.

Comment: Oh, so GHCi stops counting with `\ESC` (and maybe any unprintable character) until it sees `\STX`?

Comment: Never mind, I should read the pages I link to more carefully :)

Answer (score 3):

Haskell character escape codes are in decimal:

```
Prelude> :set prompt "\027[31mhaskell>\027[0m "
```

Putting the same directive in your `.ghci` file should also work.

Comment: You can also use e.g. `\o33` for octal escape codes, which is closer to Bash. Converting oct->dec is boring :P